# JSP: About Session in a system with login in constraint

Tags: java, jsp, session, jakarta-ee

When I am doing a project requires a login in system, I found that jsp will automatically create session, so I add <%@ page session="false" %> into all pages to disable their abilities to create session since I only want one servlet to be able to create session.

However, when it comes to using bean, I found that, I can't use bean with session scope because of <%@ page session="false" %>, I would like to ask what is the possible solution to solve this deadlock.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting session attributes from servlet(after login) then when you move to another JSP from it, the session will retain and you do not need to write

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

on that JSP. All the attributes that you set will be available for you in the session.

Here's a test code :
index page shows 'name' attribute set in servlet - MaintainSession also when you press 'next JSP' button, it takes you to another new JSP which again shows the 'name' attribute.

None of the JSP needs the <%@ page session="false" %>.

index.jsp

```
    <body>
        <form action="MaintainSession" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Set Session Attribs"/>
        </form>
        <h1>Name : ${sessionScope.name}</h1>
        <h1>Name : <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></h1>
        <form action="Next.jsp" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Next JSP"/>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Next.jsp

```
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <h1>Name : ${sessionScope.name}</h1>
        <h1>Name : <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></h1>
    </body>
```

MaintainSession.java

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
       HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("name", "MyName");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

The flow :

```
index.jsp ----Press Set Session Attribs---> MaintainSession servlet ----> index.jsp ---- press Next JSP ----> Next.jsp
```